# Не могу получить данные из CSV используя Apache POI,ошибка NotOLE2FileException

Tags: java, csv, apache-poi

Пытаюсь прочитать данные из файла.Прошу помочь разобраться почему возникает данная ошибка с CSV файлом? Этот файл был скачан. Если я создаю XLS или XLSM файл, то проблем не возникает, все работает.

```
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellType;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import static org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellType.NUMERIC;
import static org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellType.STRING;


public class Excel {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        ArrayList <Map<String,Integer>>myList=valuesInteraction();

        System.out.println(myList.get(0));
        System.out.println(myList.get(1));

    }

    public static ArrayList<Map<String,Integer>>valuesInteraction() throws IOException {

        ArrayList<Map<String,Integer>>result=new ArrayList<>();

        Map<String, Integer> interactions = new HashMap<>();
        Map<String, Integer> values = new HashMap<>();

        FileInputStream  fileIn = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\sbt-akopyan-vg\\IdeaProjects\\Excel\\zayavki.csv");
        POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem(fileIn);
        HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fs);

        HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
        for (int r = 1; r < sheet.getLastRowNum() + 1; r++) {
            StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();
            HSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(r);
            for (int c = 0; c < row.getLastCellNum(); c++) {
                CellType cellType = row.getCell(c).getCellTypeEnum();
                if (cellType == STRING) {
                    data.append(row.getCell(c).getStringCellValue());
                    data.append(" ");
                }
                if (cellType == NUMERIC) {
                    data.append(row.getCell(c).getNumericCellValue());
                    data.append(" ");
                }
            }
            String[] str = data.toString().split(" ");
            if (interactions.get(str[10]) == null) {
                interactions.put(str[10], Math.round(Float.parseFloat(str[17])));
            } else {
                interactions.put(str[10], Math.round(Float.parseFloat(str[17]) + interactions.get(str[10])));
            }

            if (values.get(str[10]) == null) {
                values.put(str[10], Math.round(1.0f));
            } else {
                values.put(str[10], Math.round(1.0f + values.get(str[10])));
            }
        }
        wb.close();

        result.add(values);
        result.add(interactions);

        return result;

    }
}
```

Вот текст ошибки:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.NotOLE2FileException: Invalid header signature; read 0xB5D0BCD0BED09DD0, expected 0xE11AB1A1E011CFD0 - Your file appears not to be a valid OLE2 document
at org.apache.poi.poifs.storage.HeaderBlock.<init>(HeaderBlock.java:144)
at org.apache.poi.poifs.storage.HeaderBlock.<init>(HeaderBlock.java:113)
at org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.NPOIFSFileSystem.<init>(NPOIFSFileSystem.java:301)
at org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem.<init>(POIFSFileSystem.java:81)
at Excel.valuesInteraction(Excel.java:45)
at Excel.main(Excel.java:30)
```

Answer (score 0):

Для чтения CSV файлов следует использовать [Apache Commons CSV](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/), а Apache POI предназначен исключительно для работы с файлами XLS, XLSX.

Comment: Игорь, а не подскажете сайт где можно примеры посмотреть с этой библиотекой?

Comment: Я же привёл ссылку в ответе. Вот ещё [User Guide](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/user-guide.html) на том же сайте.